# Cannot Scrape exposed Docker Metrics from Prometheus container when in custom network (on Linux Host)

Tags: docker, prometheus, metrics

We have a `Prometheus` container and various other services and `metrics exporter` containers running in a **custom docker network**.

In our local dev environment on Win 10 x64 using `Docker desktop` everything works fine, the `Prometheus` container can scrape the `metrics exporter` containers in the custom network as well as the exposed `Docker metrics` from the host (Win 10).

On our Ubuntu 18.04 Linux host, latest `Prometheus 2.30.3` container scrapes the metrics exporter containers in the custom network just fine but is unable to scrape the exposed `Docker metrics` from the host.

These are the specs and config for the `Ubuntu` host:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Prometheus: 2.30.3 (latest)
Docker: 20.10.10 (latest, allows to add extra hosts to container, see below)
Docker-compose: 2.0.1
```

docker metrics config in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
  "experimental": true,
  "metrics-addr": "0.0.0.0:9933"
}
```

config in `/prometheus.yml`:

```
...
 - job_name: 'docker_metrics'
    metrics_path: /metrics
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:9933']
...
```

`docker-compose` config for Prometheus container:

```
...

prometheus:
    container_name: prom_test
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.30.3
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
                  --storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus
                  --storage.tsdb.retention.time=45d"
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    volumes:
      - ./data/prometheus:/prometheus
      - ./config/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml:ro
    extra_hosts:
      host.docker.internal: host-gateway
    networks:
      - test-network

...
```

We specify `extra hosts` in the container config via `host.docker.internal: host-gateway`, which adds the Linux host's IP address to the container's `/etc/hosts` file.

When I access `Prometheus` at `https://<my_ip>:9090/targets` to inspect the status of the scrape targets, Prometheus ultimately then states:

[image]

But, clicking on the `http://host.docker.internal:9933/metrics` link provided in the scrape target endpoint block actually lists the Docker metrics

[image]

jumping into the running `Prometheus` container and executing `cat /etc/hosts` inside the container shows that the `extra host` was added correctly

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.1      host.docker.internal
172.22.0.2      fa87b35d3923
```

running `wget` inside the `Prometheus` container on the Docker metrics endpoint results in a timeout:

```
/prometheus $ wget host.docker.internal:9933/metrics
Connecting to host.docker.internal:9933 (172.17.0.1:9933)
wget: can't connect to remote host (172.17.0.1): Connection timed out
```

The problem - on **Linux** - seems to be that `Prometheus` cannot access the host when inside a **custom Docker network**. When I remove the custom network and set `network_mode: host` on the `Prometheus` service in `docker-compose`, then `Prometheus` is able to scrape the host `Docker metrics` but it cannot access the other `metrics exporter` containers inside the custom network anymore.

How can I collect metrics from the `metrics exporter` containers (in the custom network) as well as collect host `Docker metrics` on Linux ?

Thanks !

Comment: are you using `Docker-for-Linux` or normal package manager docker daemon installation? also what distro are you using? and just to clarify, did the same exact compose file work in `windows docker desktop`? try also using `--network=host`

Comment: Do you think this is something very specific to your setup? I just tried running Ubuntu, installing docker/docker compose and starting up a prom/prometheus with exactly the same config and everything just worked. I wonder if your setup is easily reproducible (in a way when it doesn't work).

Comment: @NoamYizraeli: this is a Digital Ocean server running Ubuntu 18.04, `docker` and `docker-compose` were pre-installed. The respective versions are all stated in the OP. As stated in the OP, the local dev env (hence NOT the DO server)  is Win10 x64 running Docker Desktop using Linux containers, and there all is working just fine.

Where exactly do you want me to implement --network=host ?

Comment: @jabbson: well that is exactly the question ;-) Is this specific to my setup and if so, what is the culprit ? I've stated all configs in the OP.

Comment: Clearly it is, since the running the same k8s setup in GCP didn't give me any problems, i would assume it has something to so with that being DO infrastructure (have you tried their support?) or with how you configure thing, and if so, it has everything to do with something other than the configurations and the setup explained here, because sadly I could repro however i tried.

Comment: As @jabbson said it's probably the DO config for the server, maybe try running an Ubuntu vm on your windows machine to compare? Or a free EC2 instance on aws?

Comment: @jabbson  and Noam Yizraeli
Thanks for the responses, unsure how to proceed. A very important part of the OP was that I did test accessing the Docker metrics from other containers - on the exact same DO server - and it did work, it's just the Prometheus container that is not able to access the Docker metrics. So IMO this disqualifies it being a DO configuration issue...

Comment: since reproducing the issue seems to be rather difficult (I couldn't), I can only guess here, but given other containers can access host's metrics, there must be something different either with the prometheus container or with how the host processes and passes the requests (or responses) between prometheus container and itself. Tracing iptables (is there anything non-standard about the rules, were there any manual additions?) and capturing traffic is where I would go next, I think. Also is there any connectivity to the `host.docker.internal`, can you ping it from the prometheus container?

Comment: @jabbson
No, I cannot, there is an example in the OP how I tested that via `wget`

Comment: @pete19 please share `docker inspect` of your 2 containers (the prometheus one and the curl one). Or you can just share only the network setting if you have `jq` installed by using this command `docker inspect <your_container_id> | jq '.[].NetworkSettings'`. To get the container id, use `docker ps`.

Comment: @pete19 the point was to check protocols other than http.

Comment: @all: I've updated the OP to clarify a few things, after having done more testing. Lmk if this is clear or you need more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

figured this out:

in our case `UFW` on `Ubuntu` was blocking the requests on `docker0` interface from our containers that are in a **custom docker network**.

You can see this by checking the UFW logs, you will see how it blocks the requests for `172.17.0.1` (--> host.docker.internal) on the specified metrics port.

Disabling UFW temporarily made it work, `Prometheus` could now scrape the Docker metrics on the host.

Re-enabled UFW, then...

(1) gave a custom interface name to my custom docker network

```
networks:
  my_nw:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.bridge.name: my_nw_if
```

(2) added a UFW rule to allow traffic on the the custom network interface for the metrics port solved the issue
`sudo ufw allow in on <custom_interface_name> to any port <port>`

This now allows the `Prometheus` container to scrape the metrics on the host on that port.

Thanks to everybody here who chimed in !